# Multi Category or What in Joomla?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, categories

Nowadays I have been planing the development of a huge sport site with high traffic.

Site will be content based site.

I want to use Joomla in this site.But I have problems Joomla isnot permit multiple-categories for articles because of its nature.(Joomla's database architecture is designed to related one article with only one category).

But I need multiple categories.Because I have teams and leagues/cups.I think that, a team is a category but league/cup is also a category.A team can play in both a league and cup.So with Joomla, it's not possible to build such a structure.

I googled multi-category for Joomla.There are some components which promise to succeed this problem.But as I saw their code, they use a relation table to related one article with multiple categories.Ok, it works well with their component but core modules are not aware of the relation table.

I also examined some CCKs (K2,seblod and cobalt). But I am not sure they can help me. And I also suspect from the performance of CCKs.As I told above, site will be under heavy traffic.

I want to get your ideas what can be done for this?

Answer (score 1):

**Hopefully there will be tagging to solve this problem in Joomla 3.1 (in March)** but if you want you could [check out the code for the feature](http://joomlacode.org/gf/project/joomla/tracker/?action=TrackerItemEdit&tracker_item_id=29855) now although it does require some changes to core files and is still under development (notice it is not set to ready for review).

Depending on the time frame for delivery of the site that might be workable. The only thing is you will probably want to make custom overrides for the layouts.

Comment: And yes here will be tags for 3.1, the feature was merged yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

Of course and CCK will work slower than native solution. But if you are so concern about speed I would not even start with Joomla.

But what i know for sure that Cobalt 8 is perfectly optimised. And if there is CCK that works quick it is a Cobalt. They invested a lot into optimisation. Sections with 50 000 article plus 3 relation fields in 1.5s. That pretty much impressive comparing to others. And yet they always optimise it. There was number of cases when Cobalt customers complained for slowness. Those was fixed by the next update (and they release updates every Thursday).

Another thing that Cobalt has Multilevelselect field that can completely replace categories. You can set it multiple times and you can add multiple fields. This usually works as solution in cases lice this. Because this field has filters. So you can search or filter through.